# Google+ Hangout button has stopped showing

Tags: google-hangouts

Following is the html needed to show Hangout button on any website.

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<g:hangout render="createhangout"></g:hangout>
```

https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/button

This code and its other variants were functioning propery few days back, suddenly the button is not visible anymore. A white rectangle has taken its place. When inspected i see that white button has a white background, and so the rectangle is there.

Is there anyone facing the same issue ? Any explaination is appreciated..

Comment: This is also happening to me, it definitely seems like a Google bug, let's hope someone from Google sees this and fixes the problem.

Comment: It looks like, Google has resolved it today!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as well. It seems google has fixed the problem. The button rendered correctly today.